# cleartool: Error: "Unable to transfer a file: Permission denied"

Tags: clearcase-ucm, cleartool

I have a stream ClearCase (UCM)  stream.  The snapshot view update started failing with error.

```
cleartool: Error: Unable to access "C:\views\qe-lis_2014.1\ctools_src\src\chsboot\test\exe\jcechecksumtest.exe.loading": Permission denied.
cleartool: Error: Unable to transfer a file: Permission denied.
cleartool: Error: Unable to copy "c\cdft\b\1f\65a681eb2ed247f7850957f17516b8cd" to "C:\views\qe-lis_2014.1\ctools_src\src\chsboot\test\exe\jcechecksumtest.exe.loading": Permission denied.
cleartool: Error: Unable to load "jcechecksumtest.exe".
```

A dynamic view on same stream on same machine works fine.    A snapshot view created from another machine works fine too. How can I find more information on this and fix the error?

**Versions**

```
machine with error: ClearCase 7.1.1.4 (Windows NT 6.1 (build 7601) Service Pack 1 Pentium)
machine working fine: ClearCase 7.1.1.3 (Windows NT 6.1 (build 7601) Service Pack 1 Pentium)
```

**Edit #1**

I do not have admin rights

Comment: Did your computer or the server recently have a hard drive crash?  Also if you're dealing with a permissions issue, this might help http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266913

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  It was not rebooted for a while. After the error came, I restarted the machine.  The error is same when I create another snapshot view on the same machine and same stream.  I will try from another machine an update here

Comment: Do you have admin access to the repo?

Comment: No.  I have only normal access. You may request any commands that require such access. we have a team with admin access, it may take some time before I get to run them.

Comment: Go to the control panel, open the Clearcase control panel and check that the ALBD Service is running under the `Services Startup` tab.  If it's not running, click the `Start ClearCase` button

Answer (score 1):

One way to troubleshoot is to ask the ClearCase admin to go to the vob server, in `c\cdft\b\1f\` and check if the permissions are somehow different from the other elements.

As mentioned in [this old thread](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000013995751):

> There are a bunch of steps for cleaning permissions (e.g. `protectvob`, `cleartool protect`) that should always be run you restore from backup.
>   Fundamentally, you want to check the vob permissions on the physical repository and the permissions as you see them from within a view.
>   Also check your view storage - even better create new views.

On the client side, you can check if the issue persists with:

- other snapshot views on your computer
- other snapshot views (on the same UCM stream) for other users (on other computers)
- make sure your `CLEARCASE_PRIMARY_GROUP` environment variable is still set to the primary group of the Vob you want to access.

Since another view on another machine works, you can compare their properties by doing:

```
cd /path/to/snapshot:view
cleartool lsview -l -full -pro -cview
```