# clearcase multisite-check if there are checkedout files/directory on a stream

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm, cleartool

We are using clearcase multisite with UCM.  How can I check if there are checkout files/directories on a given stream  even if the stream is mastered somewhere else?

Currently I am using 
`cleartool lsact -long`  (from a view created on the stream) that gives output that has string 'CHECKEDOUT'. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

> `cleartool lsact -long`

That seems one efficient way, since the activity will reflect in its change sets the files currently checked out.

You are, I believe from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23799202/6309), in CC 7.1

Another approach would be to try, as in [Rational ClearCase commands related to Rational ClearCase MultiSite](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ms_admin.doc/r_related_ct_cmds.htm)

```
cleartool lsco -areplicas
```

> Lists checked-out versions in all replicas of a VOB (Default: lists your current replica’s checkouts)
>
> Lists checkouts of the element specified by `pname` in all replicas of the VOB that contains `pname`.
>   If you do not specify any `pname` arguments, lists all checkouts in all replicas of the VOB that contains the current working directory.

That might be longer to process though (that a `lsact -l` on a well-defined activity), unless you limit the `lsco` to a current folder.

Comment: @Jayan maybe because the vob isn't in sync with the replicas? If it is, then your approach remains better.